# Adding Words Together

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

No matter how far I've roamed, I've never found anything quite as perplexing as this puzzle. Perhaps you can help me find the missing numeral in the last line.

```
EXIT + LAX = 71
BROCCOLI + MASSIVE = 1255
SCANDAL + CLIENT = 601
DELIGHT + EMULSIVE = 1605
ADVISE + NAVY = 511
SIX + CANDLE = 459
DECEIT + DECEIVE = 1205
MEDIA + ALIVE = ?
```

*Suggestions for improvement welcome*

Comment: Could the first line be correctly written as "EXIT + LAX = 701"?

Comment: @Brandon_J Nope, EXIT + LAX = 71 and no other number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The missing step is to

> Remove extra letters so that the words can be read as Roman numerals.

The equations are

> EXIT + LAX = XI + LX = 11 + 60 = 71
>  BROCCOLI + MASSIVE = CCLI + MIV = 251 + 1004 = 1255
>  SCANDAL + CLIENT = CDL + CLI = 450 + 151 = 601
>  DELIGHT + EMULSIVE = DLI + MLIV = 551 + 1054 = 1605
>  ADVISE + NAVY = DVI + V = 506 + 5 = 511
>  SIX + CANDLE = IX + CDL = 9 + 450 = 459
>  DECEIT + DECEIVE = DCI + DCIV = 601 + 604 = 1205

So the answer is

> MEDIA + ALIVE = MDI + LIV = 1501 + 54 = **1555**

Comment: Good one! These Roman numeral puzzles seem kind of popular these days.

Comment: that's it, and yes you found an error!